# Solve $\int e^{\cos x}\frac{x \sin^3x+\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int e^{\cos x} \left(\frac{x \sin^3x+\cos x}{\sin^2x}\right)dx$$

At first look, i thought $\int e^x(f(x)+f'(x))dx$ will be applied but not applicable in this case.
Then i used integration by parts but that is not working either.How should i solve it,please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle  I = \int e^{\cos x}\left(\frac{x\sin^3 x+\cos x}{\sin^2 x}\right)dx = \int xe^{\cos x}\cdot \sin xdx+\int e^{\cos x}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}dx = I+J$

Now Integration By parts for 1 st Integral

$\displaystyle I = -xe^{\cos x}+\int e^{\cos x}dx$

Now Integration by parts for Second Integral

$\displaystyle J = \int e^{\cos x}\frac{\cos x}{\sin ^2x} dx = -e^{\cos x}\frac{1}{\sin x}-\int e^{\cos x}dx$

Comment: $\displaystyle \int xe^{\cos x}\cdot \sin xdx \;,$ Put $\cos x = t\;,$ Then $\sin xdx = -dt$ So Our Integral is $\displaystyle = -x\int e^{t}dt +\int \left[\left(\int e^{t}\right)dt\right]dx = -xe^{\cos x}+\int e^{\cos x}dx$

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $t=\cos(x)$ to get

$$\int e^t \left(\arccos(t)-\frac t{(1-t^2)^{3/2}}\right)dt$$

and apply your technique with a plus/minus trick:

$$\int e^t \left(\arccos(t)-\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}+\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}-\frac t{(1-t^2)^{3/2}}\right)dt=e^t\arccos(t)+\frac{e^t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.$$

Comment: Sign error(s) to be expected :)

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Integrate by parts,

$$\int x\cdot e^{\cos x}\sin x\ dx$$ and

$$\int e^{\cos x}\cdot\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx$$